# Phase Congruency edge / corner detection algorithm

Tags: c#, computer-vision, fft, aforge, edge-detection

Is there any available code, or even pseudocode, that would allow me to implement the Phase Congruency edge / corner detection algorithm in C#?

I am far from a math expert when it comes to the frequency domain.

The only available (functioning) source that I can find is for matlab, which has a huge math library that isn't available to C#.  If I could understand these functions better and find similar C# functions, it would help a lot.

I am using Accord.NET (which includes AForge.NET), so there are a handful of functions to work with images and FFTs.

Comment: I'm not aware of any C# implementations that are public that do phase congruency. Like you said, the closest alternative is the one in [Matlab](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/index.html#phasecong). Also, note that phase congruency is not really an edge detector; it's a line detector... which may serve a different function than you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can certainly try to use:

```
       Harris corner detector (implemented in Accord.NET)

       SIFT (although it reacts on blobs it can react on edges as well)  (implemented in Accord.NET)

       SUSAN (AForge or Accord.NET ?)
```

...

Read Accord.NET and AForge.NET documentation. I know they implemented several corner finding algorithms.